# $f:D\to D$ is analytic then $f^{n_i}(z)$ converges pointwise for all $z$

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, analytic-functions, pointwise-convergence

This is a problem from my past Qual.

"Let $D$ denote the unit disk and $f:D\to D$ be analytic. Show that there exists a sequence $n_i$ s.t. $f^{n_i}(z)$ converges pointwise for all $z\in D$. Here $f^n=f\circ f\circ\ldots\circ f$ ($n$ times)."

I have no idea how to start. I have an analytic function, so I have its Taylor series in a small neighborhood, I know the Cauchy-Riemann equations. That's it. I mean usually when I deal with $f^n$, I study $f$. In this case it seems I don't have a lot of information to study $f^n$. So I'm stuck here.

Comment: Did you mean $f^n(z)-(f(z))^n$? or $f^n(z)=(f^{n-1}\circ f)(z)$, $f^1=f$, In the former, isn't it  trivial? $|f^n(z)|=|f(z)|^n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$ since $|f(z)|<1$.

Comment: oh no this is composition.

Comment: That's what I thought. I edited your question to add composition symbols to avoid confusion.

Comment: This seems to be related to what is known as normal families. See pages 281-282  of Rudin's real and complex analysis. In particular Theorem14.6

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ is a holomorphic function on the unit disc in $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that all coefficients of all functions $f^n$ have modulus at most $1$, by their Cauchy integral formula.  Since the closed unit disc is compact, it follows that there is a subsequence $f^{n_k}$ such that their coefficients (viewed as functions $\mathbb{N}\to \overline{\mathbb{D}}$) converge pointwise to a sequence $a_0, a_1, \ldots$ in the closed unit disc. Set $g(z)=\sum_ka_kz^k$. This is a holomorphic function on the unit disc. Then show that the sequence of functions $f^{n_k}$ converges pointwise to $g$ on the unit disc. (For example, consider only the first $m$ terms in their series and derive a pointwise bound depending om $m$, then take $m \to \infty$.)

Comment: Which coefficients are you referring to?  Do you mean the Taylor coefficients?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Yes, the Taylor coefficients at $z=0$.

Comment: The family described in the problem is a normal family since $f^{n}=f\circ\ldots\circ f$ ($n$ times) is in fact uniformly bound. One can either used a theorem that states that families of holomorphic functions in a region that are uniformly bounded in compact subsets are normal (meaning every subsequence has a uniform convergent subsequence etc) or use Cauchy estimates to prove Lipschitz condition and some versions of the Ascolli-Arzela theorem.