# A subsequence of $f^n$ converge pointwise where $f$ is analytic on the unit ball

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions, pointwise-convergence

This is a problem from my past Qual: "Let $\Omega$ be the unit disk and $f:\Omega\to \Omega$ be an analytic function. COnsider the sequence $\{f^n(z)\}$ where $f^n=f\circ\ldots\circ f$ ($n$--times). Prove that there is a subsequence that converges for every $z$."

I learn from Ahlfors' COmplex Analysis. And I don't think there is any tool in there that concern $f^n$. SO I don't even know where to approach. Since we are dealing with unit disk, Schwarz lemma comes to mind, but still there is barely any information to work with.

Comment: check out Montel's theorem $f^{(n)}$ is uniformly bounded by $1$ so it has a normally (uniform on compact subsets) convergent subsequence https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montel%27s_theorem

Comment: thank you. I see it now

Comment: This question has been asked twice https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3694765/fd-to-d-is-analytic-then-fn-iz-converges-pointwise-for-all-z

Comment: happy to be of help